# Back to the top of file?

Tags: python, file

I have a program where I'm reading numbers from a file and adding those numbers to different lists in my program. Now, I need to jump back to the top of the file and read from the top again. Does anyone know if there is a command that does that or if its even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seek(0)` to start from the beginning all over again.

Actually, when you read from a file, it continuously updates the offset to the current bytes. `seek()` provides you with the ability to set the offset at any position.

At the beginning, offset is located at 0. So, `f.seek(0)` will set the offset at the beginning of the file.

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    f.read(100) # Read first 100 byte     
    f.seek(0) # set the offset at the beginning
    f.read(50) # Read first 50 byte again.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. Simplest one is using `seek(0)`. `0` represents start of the file.

You can even use `tell()` to store any position of the file and reuse it:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_position = f.tell()
    f.read() # your read 
    f.seek(first_position)  # it will take you to the previous position you marked.
```

Comment: What is the second way?

Comment: seek(0) can used without storing the position.